# What does this Revolution jQuery do

Tags: javascript, jquery, revolution-slider

I was reading some code today and came across this. This is using the Revolution slider with extensions, link to their site [here](https://revolution.themepunch.com/jquery/). I'm not entirely sure what this huge piece of code does, and was wondering if there was anyone that could help me out with this. In the code, it says navigation, so is this how the website makes its navigation bar? I was viewing the actual code and noticed that no-where in the code was there an actual place that made the navigation bar. So I'm assuming they used this or some other JavaScript to insert the nav-bar without coding it directly in HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tpj=jQuery;
    var revapi4;
    tpj(window).load(function() {
        if(tpj("#rev_slider_4_1").revolution == undefined){
            revslider_showDoubleJqueryError("#rev_slider_4_1");
        }else{
            revapi4 = tpj("#rev_slider_4_1").show().revolution({
                sliderType:"standard",
                jsFileLocation:"assets/revolution/js/",
                sliderLayout:"fullscreen",
                dottedOverlay:"none",
                delay:9000,
                navigation: {
                    keyboardNavigation: "on",
                    keyboard_direction: "horizontal",
                    mouseScrollNavigation: "off",
                    onHoverStop: "off",
                    touch: {
                        touchenabled: "on",
                        swipe_threshold: 75,
                        swipe_min_touches: 1,
                        swipe_direction: "horizontal",
                        drag_block_vertical: false
                    },
                    arrows: {
                        style: "gyges",
                        enable: true,
                        hide_onmobile: false,
                        hide_onleave: false,
                        tmp: '',
                        left: {
                            h_align: "left",
                            v_align: "center",
                            h_offset: 10,
                            v_offset: 0
                        },
                        right: {
                            h_align: "right",
                            v_align: "center",
                            h_offset: 10,
                            v_offset: 0
                        }
                    },
                    bullets: {
                        enable: false,
                        hide_onmobile: false,
                        style: "gyges",
                        hide_onleave: false,
                        direction: "horizontal",
                        h_align: "center",
                        v_align: "top",
                        h_offset: 0,
                        v_offset: 20,
                        space: 5,
                        tmp: ''
                    }
                },
                parallax: {
                    type:"mouse",
                    origo:"slidercenter",
                    speed:2000,
                    levels:[2,3,4,5,6,7,12,16,10,50],
                },
                responsiveLevels:[1240,1024,778,480],
                gridwidth:[1240,1024,778,480],
                gridheight:[868,768,960,720],
                lazyType:"none",
                shadow:0,
                spinner:"off",
                stopLoop:"on",
                stopAfterLoops:0,
                stopAtSlide:1,
                shuffle:"off",
                autoHeight:"off",
                fullScreenAlignForce:"off",
                fullScreenOffsetContainer: "",
                fullScreenOffset: "",
                disableProgressBar:"on",
                hideThumbsOnMobile:"off",
                hideSliderAtLimit:0,
                hideCaptionAtLimit:0,
                hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,
                debugMode:false,
                fallbacks: {
                    simplifyAll:"off",
                    nextSlideOnWindowFocus:"off",
                    disableFocusListener:false,
                }
            });
        }
    }); /*ready*/
</script>
```

Thanks a bunch, I appreciate the help!

Comment: this is the initialization of the revolution slider,what don't you understand ?

Comment: btw this plugin has a freaking large list of setting man lol :(

Comment: Oh, i guess I'm just unsure of where the navigation bar comes from then. In the HTML it never initializes a nav-bar, so was confused as to where that's made ---- It uses the Revolution Scroll navigation, but not sure where/how it's made I guess

Comment: the plugin creates the necessary structure using the setting provided

Comment: So with the settings (mainly the navigation portion), the plugin creates this sites nav-bar. Generating whatever the code may be on its own, I'm understanding you and this correctly (right)?

Comment: not maybe it does it , how do you think the html appears on the page magic?